# Easy Access to robot poses created using the MoveIt! Setup Assistant

Tags: ros, moveit, move-group-interface, moveit-setup-assistant

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Consider that I have set 3 different poses for my robot with different names and different joint values.

Now while using the `MoveIt Setup Assistant` I can add the 3 poses under the tab `Robot Poses`and click the button `MoveIt!` at the bottom of the Setup Assistant screen to see the robot change the poses.

I want to know how I can easily switch between the 3 poses when I am using the `move_group_interface` and the `RViz plugin`.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/253399/easy-access-to-robot-poses-created-using-the-moveit!-setup-assistant/) by [R.Mehra](https://answers.ros.org/users/26660/r.mehra/) on ROS Answers with karma: 49 on 2017-01-31

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Those poses are called *named targets*.

Using them in C++: [moveit::planning_interface::MoveGroup::setNamedTarget(const std::string &name)](http://docs.ros.org/indigo/api/moveit_ros_planning_interface/html/classmoveit_1_1planning__interface_1_1MoveGroup.html#af6850334bb1b4f12e457257550d5f92c).

In the RViz planning plugin: select them from the drop-down under *Select Goal State* on the *Planning* tab.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-01-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Jasmin](https://answers.ros.org/users/28536/jasmin/) on 2019-09-10**:
Is there a way to do the same thing with `Python`?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-09-10**:
I believe it was added in [ros-planning/moveit#1300](https://github.com/ros-planning/moveit/pull/1300).

**Comment by [Jasmin](https://answers.ros.org/users/28536/jasmin/) on 2019-09-10**:
Perfect! thank you @gvdhoorn .